# using shell script ,replicate a record from a file 1000 times or n times by incrementing few records

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a record in a file named abc.txt as below:

```
ID, date, timestamp, count, idcount, unit, code, Pcode, ccode, bid, vcode

12345432,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
```

I want to write a unix shell code to generate more no. of record by just incrementing the column ID,Pcode and ccode and remaining column as it is.

```
12345432,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds

12345433,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,15,20,123454323,qweds

12345434,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,16,21,123454323,qweds

12345435,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,17,22,123454323,qweds

12345436,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,18,23,123454323,qweds

12345437,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,19,24,123454323,qweds
.
.
.
.
1000 times or n times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be shell, or would e.g. `awk` do? Like

```
awk -F, -v"CNT=10" 'NR==1; NR==2 {for (;CNT--;) {print; $1++; $8++; $9++}}' OFS=, file
ID, date, timestamp, count, idcount, unit, code, Pcode, ccode, bid, vcode
12345432,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345433,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345434,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345435,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345436,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345437,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345438,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345439,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345440,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345441,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
```

CNT times `print` the second line with an incremented first field.

If it has to be shell, try

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
CNT=10
{ read LINE; echo $LINE; read LINE; } <file1
IFS=, ARR=($LINE)
while ((CNT--))
  do    ((ARR[0]++ + ARR[7]++ + ARR[8]++))
        echo "${ARR[*]}"
  done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Make sure the count is set upfront else you will end up with quite large a result file...

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the blank lines in the input and output in the question are not actually there. Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`), first clean up the extra whitespaces present in the header and then create `$n` copies of the single data record.  We then pass this through a second Miller invocation to update the records, incrementing the named `ID`, `Pcode` and `ccode` columns.

```bash
mlr --csv clean-whitespace then bootstrap -n "$n" file |
mlr --csv put '
    NR == 1 { @ID=$ID; @Pcode=$Pcode; @ccode=$ccode }
    NR > 1 {
        $ID    = @ID    + NR - 1;
        $Pcode = @Pcode + NR - 1;
        $ccode = @ccode + NR - 1;
    }'
```

Given the data in the question, and with `n=10` in the shell, this would output

```
ID,date,timestamp,count,idcount,unit,code,Pcode,ccode,bid,vcode
12345432,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345433,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,15,20,123454323,qweds
12345434,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,16,21,123454323,qweds
12345435,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,17,22,123454323,qweds
12345436,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,18,23,123454323,qweds
12345437,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,19,24,123454323,qweds
12345438,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,20,25,123454323,qweds
12345439,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,21,26,123454323,qweds
12345440,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,22,27,123454323,qweds
12345441,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,23,28,123454323,qweds
```

---

Using `awk` and ignoring the cleanup of the header, and assuming we know that the fields we want to update are fields 1, 8, and 9.  Also, since `awk` is not CSV-aware, we must assume that we are dealing with "simple CSV" data, i.e. data not containing fields with embedded commas or newlines.

```bash
awk -v n="$n" '
    BEGIN { OFS=FS="," }
    NR==1 { print; next }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
            print
            $1++; $8++; $9++
        }
    }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v n=10 '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    { print }
    NR > 1 { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) { $1++; $8++; $9++; print } }
' abc.txt
ID, date, timestamp, count, idcount, unit, code, Pcode, ccode, bid, vcode
12345432,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,14,19,123454323,qweds
12345433,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,15,20,123454323,qweds
12345434,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,16,21,123454323,qweds
12345435,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,17,22,123454323,qweds
12345436,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,18,23,123454323,qweds
12345437,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,19,24,123454323,qweds
12345438,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,20,25,123454323,qweds
12345439,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,21,26,123454323,qweds
12345440,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,22,27,123454323,qweds
12345441,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,23,28,123454323,qweds
12345442,10-11-2011,11:11:12.555,0,0,XVC_AS,12,24,29,123454323,qweds
```